# formname.submit not working on IE8

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am currently developing an app and i am getting difficulties on IE8.

I have the following code:

```
<form class="fillClaimForm" name="fillClaimForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php print BASE_URL; ?>?action=insertBlogger" >
   <label for="fblogName">Blog's name: </label>
   <input type="text" name="fblogName" id="fblogName" class="cfInput" placeholder ="Complex" required />
   <label for="fblogUrl">URL: </label>
   <input type="text" name="fblogUrl" id="fblogUrl" class="cfInput" placeholder ="www.complex.com" required />
   <label>Blog's logo: </label>
   <div class="upload-file-container"><span>UPLOAD</span>
   <input  type="file" name="fblogLogo" id="fblogLogo"/>
   <p class="ErrLoad error" style="display:none;">Please load your logo</p>
   </div>
    <label for="fEmail">Email adresse: </label>
    <input  type="email" name="fEmail" id="fEmail" class="cfInput" required />
    <label for="frNum">Phone number: </label>
    <input  type="tel"  name="frNum" id="frNum" class="cfInput" required />
    <input type="hidden" name="idVid" id ="idVid" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="idRubrique" id ="idRubrique" value=""/>
    <button id="sendClaim" class="sendClaim">SEND</button>
```

Consequently, I am doing a form submission using jquery:

```
......submit(function(){
        validate=false;
        formInfo = validateForm(validate,$thisLi);
        if(formInfo.validate){
            **fillClaimForm.submit();**
        }
        return false;
    });
```

It is working on all browsers except IE8

Can someone kindly help me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a click event? Is your form tag closed with </form>

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your form.
Also give the same name as the id for your form and use

```
$("#formId").submit();
```

Code

```
<form class="fillClaimForm" name="fillClaimForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php print BASE_URL; ?>?action=insertBlogger" >
   <label for="fblogName">Blog's name: </label>
   <input type="text" name="fblogName" id="fblogName" class="cfInput" placeholder ="Complex" required />
   <label for="fblogUrl">URL: </label>
   <input type="text" name="fblogUrl" id="fblogUrl" class="cfInput" placeholder ="www.complex.com" required />
   <label>Blog's logo: </label>
   <div class="upload-file-container"><span>UPLOAD</span>
   <input  type="file" name="fblogLogo" id="fblogLogo"/>
   <p class="ErrLoad error" style="display:none;">Please load your logo</p>
   </div>
    <label for="fEmail">Email adresse: </label>
    <input  type="email" name="fEmail" id="fEmail" class="cfInput" required />
    <label for="frNum">Phone number: </label>
    <input  type="tel"  name="frNum" id="frNum" class="cfInput" required />
    <input type="hidden" name="idVid" id ="idVid" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="idRubrique" id ="idRubrique" value=""/>
    <button id="sendClaim" class="sendClaim">SEND</button>
</form>

$("#sendClaim").click(function(){
        validate=false;
        formInfo = validateForm(validate,$thisLi);
        if(formInfo.validate){
            $("#fillClaimForm").submit();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.forms.fillClaimForm.submit();
```

Or if the  `......` in your code represents creating of a submit handler on that same form you can probably just say `this.submit()`.

Comment: Tried the code. It is submitting the form but the post values are null despite having inputed data!

Comment: Consequently I used document.forms[0].fillClaimForm.submit(); and all fine :)